# Can you have 2 processes modify a data store in a DFD diagram

Tags: development-process, diagrams, process, system

If I have a `Ban User` process that should definitely modify the `Accounts` data store and if I have `Create Account` that should also should modify the `Accounts` data store.

Comment: An example diagram of how you intend to make a DFD which shows modification to a data store by a process would be helpful (its IMHO quite unusual, in DFDs, processes usually take some input, and produce some output, but they don't modify the input in-place). Also, you did not tell us why you ask - what gives you objections for having 2 processes accessing the same data store?

Answer (score 0):

DFD's are a documentation tool having a somewhat defined language, but you won't get fined if you use them slightly differently from how they "should" be used. You just shouldn't use them in confusing ways. So your "can you have" question can generally be answered "yes if you like".

That said, as all diagrams only show a limited aspect of your system, it is perfectly normal for separate diagrams to use/modify the same resource. In your example, the actions have preconditions (`ban user` can only ban existing users, `create account` can only create accounts that don't exist before) and depending on the modeling language you might need to explicitly model synchronization, or it might be assumed in the form of transactions or other atomicity mechanisms.

The question here is how you got the impression that two processes can't modify the same resource. There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding about how software works or about what you can express with DFD's.